# Use MeasurementFormatter to display meters as feet

Tags: ios, swift3, nsmeasurementformatter, measurementformatter

I'm having trouble getting the new `MeasurementFormatter` class to give me results in appropriate units. I have values in meters that I want to display in localized strings, either meters or feet depending on the user's locale.

I have this:

```
let meters : Double = 10
let metersMeasurement = Measurement(value: meters, unit: UnitLength.meters)

let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
measurementFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

let localizedString = measurementFormatter.string(from: metersMeasurement)
```

This gives me a string of "0.006mi". It's correct, I guess, but converting 10 meters to miles is kind of ridiculous. What I want is "32.8ft".

The `.providedUnit` option on `MeasurementFormatter` isn't helpful-- that just gives me a result in meters.

I could look up the current locale and handle this myself, but that's exactly the kind of thing that `MeasurementFormatter` is supposed to make unnecessary. Is there some way to get it to do what I need?

Comment: Set the `naturalScale` option on your unit formatter https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/measurementformatter.unitoptions/1642065-naturalscale

Comment: Besides naturalScale you need to set the number formatter maximum digits to 1 `measurementFormatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1`

Comment: @LeoDabus That would be optional.

Comment: @LeoDabus correct, for the result I mentioned, but not the main point of the question. Thanks though.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the formatter's `unitOptions` to `naturalScale`:

```
let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
measurementFormatter.unitOptions = .naturalScale
```

And you should only set the locale if you want every user in any locale to see the value in the specific locale.

Comment: I included the locale in my question in case someone tried using that code when their locale was different from mine-- I wanted to force US units for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I also have a slightly different version of this question where this answer doesn't apply. Maybe you could [take a look at it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858828/choosing-units-with-measurementformatter)?