# How to convert Meters and Centimeters to Feets and Inches and to display them on UILabel

Tags: swift

I have a UISlider with value from 0 to 8 (meters).
I try to convert from Meters to CM, Feet, Inches and to display this values on 2 UILabels. In one label I want to show the value like: 19 ft 10" and in another label I want to show the value like: 6 m 4 cm.
I'm struggling with the conversion and maybe someone can help me display this values.

Here is my code in the View:

```
protocol VehicleHeightCellDelegate {
    func vehicleHeightSliderValueChanged(_ slider: UISlider, _ feetsLabel: UILabel, _ metersLabel: UILabel)
}

class VehicleHeightCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Interface Links
    @IBOutlet weak var vehicleHeightSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var vehicleHeightFeetsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var vehicleHeightMetersLabel: UILabel!

    // Properties
    var delegate: VehicleHeightCellDelegate?

@IBAction func vehicleHeightValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

    delegate?.vehicleHeightSliderValueChanged(vehicleHeightSlider, vehicleHeightFeetsLabel, vehicleHeightMetersLabel)
    }
}
```

Here is my code in the Controller:

```
extension ChecklistInspectionController: VehicleHeightCellDelegate{

    func vehicleHeightSliderValueChanged(_ slider: UISlider, _ feetsLabel: UILabel, _ metersLabel: UILabel) {

        let currentValue = Int(slider.value)

        let heightMeters = Measurement(value: Double(currentValue), unit: UnitLength.meters)
        let heightFeet = heightMeters.converted(to: UnitLength.feet)

        let heightCentimeters = heightMeters.converted(to: UnitLength.centimeters)
        let heightInches = heightMeters.converted(to: UnitLength.inches)


        feetsLabel.text = "\(heightFeet)" + " \(heightInches)"
        metersLabel.text = "\(heightMeters)" + " \(heightCentimeters)"
    }
}
```

The result needs to look like this:

[image]

At the moment look like this:
[image]

Thanks if you read this !

Comment: And what does the result currently look like?

Comment: See the update. Thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39860810/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in this way to keep things simple:

extension ChecklistInspectionController: VehicleHeightCellDelegate{

```
func vehicleHeightSliderValueChanged(_ slider: UISlider, _ feetsLabel: UILabel, _ metersLabel: UILabel) {

    let currentValue = Int(slider.value)
    let meters = currentValue / 100
    let centimeters = currentValue % 100
    let inches = currentValue < 3 ? 0 : round(Double(currentValue) / 2.54)
    let feet = round(inches / 12)
    let inch = round(inches.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 12))

    feetsLabel.text = "\(feet) ft" + " \(inch)\""
    metersLabel.text = "\(meters) m" + " \(centimeters) cm"

    print("\(meters) m \(centimeters) cm")
    print("\(feet) ft \(inch) \"") 
}
```

}

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the values displayed separately, you have to round your results and extract the decimal part and convert it.

Here is how you can achieve your results:

```
 //EXAMPLE
 let heightMeters = Measurement(value: 16.99, unit: UnitLength.meters)

 let heightCentimeters = heightMeters.converted(to: UnitLength.centimeters)

 //EXTRACT CM FROM METERS BY EVALUATING THE DECIMAL PART
 let cm = ceil((heightMeters.value - floor(heightMeters.value))*100)

 // GET METERS WITHOUT CM
 let meters = floor(heightMeters.value)

 let heightInches = heightMeters.converted(to: UnitLength.inches)
 let heightFeet = heightMeters.converted(to: UnitLength.feet)

 //EXTRACT INCHES FROM FT BY EVALUATING THE DECIMAL PART
 let inches = ceil((heightFeet.value - floor(heightFeet.value))*12)

 // GET FT WITHOUT INCHES
 let feet = floor(heightFeet.value)
```

***EDIT:***

> You can use ***round*** instead of ***ceil*** to automatic round to the nearest int number or you can ***round only the decimal part*** (or ***truncate*** an arbitrary amount of numbers of decimal part) in order to have decimal numbers like ***"6 m and 7.12 cm"*** or ***"12 ft and 11.4 inches"***

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet that converts feet to meters:

```
return Measurement(value: ft, unit: UnitLength.feet).converted(to: .meters).value
```

As the answer above suggested, see the documentation for all your options

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a `MeasurementFormatter`. You can use it's `numberFormatter` property to configure how you want to display the number part, that way you can remove the decimals.

If you set `unitOptions` to `.naturalScale` you'll probably get the style you want.

[Here's a link to the class reference.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter)